# Sorting based on row values with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which looks as follows

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 5, 6], [1, 8, 9],[2, 18, 9],[3, 99, 10],[3, 0.3, 5],[2, 58, 78],[4, 8, 9]]),

                   columns=['id', 'point_A', 'point_B'])
```

[image]

Now I want to create column which is the sum of both `point_A` and `point_B` row . I can do that by this code: `df["sum_of_all"] = df[["point_A","point_B"]].sum(axis = 1)`

Now I want to give sort them based on `sum_of_all`. Meaning the most sum will be `graded` as 1 and so on. Now it has to be done based on `id` , How can I do that ?

Update :

[image]
Once I have finished the sum and sorting I get the above output. Now My goal is to assigne grade based on `id`. i.e : id 2 ,index 6, -> grade = 1,id 2 in index 3 -> grade 2 , id 3 on index 4 -> grade 1 and id 3 on index 5 -> 2 and so on
Thats the expection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IICU

```
df2=df.sort_values(by=['sum_of_all','id'], ascending=[False, False])
df2['grade']=df2.groupby('id')['sum_of_all'].cumcount()+1
df2
```

Outcome

[image]